# Re-organizing the data set based on all possible combinations

Tags: r

Assuming I have a data with three individuals `A`, `B`, and `C`, and each of them has two characteristics, "year of school"(`YS`) and "number of siblings"(`NS`). Thus, the dataset `X` looks like as follows:

```
id <- c("A", "B", "C")
YS <- c(6, 9, 8)
NS <-c(1, 0, 3)
X <- data.frame(id, YS, NS)
```

Now I have to re-organize the data set based on all possible combination of `A`, `B`, and `C`, which means there will be 2^3-1 combinations. More precisely, the combinations are: `A`, `B`, `C`, `AB`, `AC`, `BC`, `ABC`, and a `null` combination (i.e., 2^3-1 combinations). In addition to combine the individuals, I also have to calculate the value of each characteristics for each combination. For instance, the values of `YS` and `NS` for the combination `AB` are 15 and 1. For another instance, the values of `YS` and `NS` for the combination `ABC` are 23 and 4.

I kind of understand to use the code `expand.grid` to generate the possible combinations, but I don't know how to combine the values of characteristics at the same time. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another option with `combn`

```
all_combn <- function(x, ...)
    unlist(sapply(seq_along(x), combn, x=x, ...))

data.frame(
   id=all_combn(id, paste, collapse=''),
   YS=all_combn(YS, sum),
   NS=all_combn(NS, sum)
)

#    id YS NS
# 1   A  6  1
# 2   B  9  0
# 3   C  8  3
# 4  AB 15  1
# 5  AC 14  4
# 6  BC 17  3
# 7 ABC 23  4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matthew (and of course everyone who helps). I have another question in this code. What does `x=x` in the second line mean? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @MatthewPlourde. Do you mind to explain the part of `sapply`? I am kind of lost there, because to me, the first element of `sapply` seems to be the names of a list, but here you use `seq_along(x)` and I don't quite get the meaning. Also, how does `x=x` function? It seems like to be used for telling `combn` what `m` is. Anyway, I will appreciate if you could explain this `sapply` part.

Comment: `sapply` iterates over the id lengths. First it makes all the combinations for 1 id, then 2 ids, then 3 ids, etc. You're right the values of `seq_along(x)` get passed to the `m` argument of `combn`, because the first argument, `x`, is specified in the `sapply` call.

Answer (score 3):

Not very pretty or R-like, but it works.  And it includes the NULL set as per the question.

```
# function to create the combinations and sum the elements
reorgCombs <- function(data) {
    ids <- rownames(data)
    newdata <- data.frame(comb = c("NULL", id), YS = c(0, data[, "YS"]), 
                          NS = c(0, data[, "NS"]), row.names = NULL)
    for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
        theseCombs <- t(combn(ids, i))
        newdata <- rbind(newdata, 
                         data.frame(comb = apply(theseCombs, 1, paste0, collapse=""),
                                    YS = apply(theseCombs, 1, function(x) sum(data[x, "YS"])),
                                    NS = apply(theseCombs, 1, function(x) sum(data[x, "NS"]))))
    }
    newdata
}

# make this a numeric matrix with named dimensions
# the names will be used for lookup
X2 <- cbind(YS, NS)
rownames(X2) <- id

reorgCombs(X)
##   comb YS NS
## 1 NULL  0  0
## 1    A  6  1
## 2    B  9  0
## 3    C  8  3
## 4   AB 15  1
## 5   AC 14  4
## 6   BC 17  3
## 7  ABC 23  4
```

**Edited with new benchmarks:**

Perhaps because of the lookup table, even despite the looping it's *relatively fast* -- but **whooped by Matthew's solution**:

```
## Unit: relative
##    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
##    jota  4.479829  4.408874  4.304705  4.455843  4.335172  3.730202   100
##  pierre 11.606636 11.623717 12.743089 12.078027 11.761123 19.271072   100
##     ken  3.034247  3.015091  2.978181  3.040916  2.914744  2.755357   100
## matthew  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
##   frank  4.572867  4.615341  4.590244  4.719418  4.516317  3.978101   100
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the benchmark. I'm surprised Matthew's wins, since it calls `combn` separately for each column.

Comment: Thanks for your help @KenBenoit

Comment: I also wonder if any of you can tell me what `x=x` stands for in the `sapply` function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it in base R. First, identify combos:

```
n = nrow(X)
combos = do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(n), function(x){
  r = combn(n, x)
  data.frame( r = c(r), g = paste(x, c(col(r)), sep=".") )
}))
```

Then, select rows of `X` for each combo:

```
Xc    = X[combos$r,]
Xc$id = as.character(Xc$id)
Xc$g  = ave(Xc$id, combos$g, FUN = function(x) paste0(x,collapse=''))
```

Finally, aggregate for each combo:

```
aggregate(cbind(YS,NS)~g, Xc, sum)

#     g YS NS
# 1   A  6  1
# 2  AB 15  1
# 3 ABC 23  4
# 4  AC 14  4
# 5   B  9  0
# 6  BC 17  3
# 7   C  8  3
```

You're missing the empty set this way, but that's easy enough to `rbind` on if desired.

Comment: I appreciate your help @Frank!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lot but I happened to be using `splitstackshape` for another answer and saw an application possibility here. The first call is `lst1 <- do.call(c, "all combinations")`. This creates the list as you mentioned of all possibilities. You can add the edge cases like `NULL` later if you would like. We create a dataframe from `lst1` to organize the information. The function `cSplit` reshapes `df` to long. We merge to add in the number values. Finally, with `dplyr` we group by the index column we created, turning any factors to type `integer`, then find the sums:

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

lst1 <- do.call(c, lapply(1:3, function(i) combn(id, i, simplify=F)))
df <- data.frame(indx=seq_along(lst1), combs=sapply(lst1, toString))
df.long <- cSplit(df, 'combs', direction="long")

m <- merge(X, df.long, by.x='id', by.y='combs')
m %>% group_by(indx) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.integer(as.character(.))), -id) %>%
  summarise(id=toString(id), YS=sum(YS), NS=sum(NS))
# Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
# 
#    indx      id    YS    NS
#   (int)   (chr) (int) (int)
# 1     1       A     6     1
# 2     2       B     9     0
# 3     3       C     8     3
# 4     4    A, B    15     1
# 5     5    A, C    14     4
# 6     6    B, C    17     3
# 7     7 A, B, C    23     4
```